# Ensure the user has filled in two UITextFields in a UIViewController before UIBarButton is Selectable in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitextfielddelegate

I have a simple `UIViewController` that contains some `UITextField`. The navigation bar at the top has a `UIBarButtonItem` (created in Storyboard) which is called *Save* which ultimately allows the user to save the entry they are typing in and therefore dismiss this `UIViewController`.

I want to enforce that the user has to at least enter in 2 or 3 text fields before the Save button becomes selectable, so it's there, but greyed out till the user fills in two specified text fields.

How would I achieve something like this?

I'm sorry for the small question, but there really isn't much more to it than this; grey out the `BarButtonItem` till the fields have been filled in and then allow the user to click on it. I've searched online and very surprisingly cannot find much information on this.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

**Update**. I have tried adding:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;` to the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` just to see if I can start disabling my bar button items and it doesn't get disabled at all.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: It seriously did - thanks so much Garbiel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything created with **Storyboards**.

First of all you need `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` for your `UIBarButton`. You can do that in your .m

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem;
@end
```

And:

```
- (IBAction)myBarButtonItemAction:(id)sender
{
    // your code
}
```

I'll suppose that you have 2 `UITextField` created with **Xcode Interface Builder**, then add them as `IBOutlet` to your .m:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFieldOne;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextFieldTwo;
```

Add this line to `viewDidLoad` to disable the `UIBarButton`:

```
self.myBarButtonItem.enabled = FALSE;
```

To take control of your `UITextField` you can do it in two ways:

**First one** with `UITextFieldDelegate`, add this code to .m

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

You can check [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

And the delegate method you need is one of this two, depending on what do you want to achieve:

```
– textFieldDidBeginEditing:
– textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

**However I don't like this approach**, because with `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` someone can begin the edit and never enter text. With `textFieldDidEndEditing:` you need to call something to dismiss the Keyboard: `[self.myTextFieldOne resignFirstResponder]`. Also you can/should implement another `UITextFieldDelegate` who take's control of the 'Return' key `– textFieldShouldReturn:`

If you decide to use the `UITextFieldDelegate` remember to add:

```
self.myTextFieldOne.delegate = self;
self.myTextFieldTwo.delegate = self;
```

Then, **my second option** is to add this line of code to `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkTextFields) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Here you receive a notification to your `SEL` every time the text is changed into a `UITextField`

then:

```
- (void) checkTextFields
{
    // Add here your logic to check TextFields and decide if they have text
    if ([self.myTextFieldOne.text length] != 0 && [self.myTextFieldTwo.text length] != 0)
    {
        self.myBarButtonItem.enabled = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        self.myBarButtonItem.enabled = FALSE;
    }
}
```

You can check a [small demo with my second option here.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification)

Comment: Dear Gabriel - Thank you so much for your excellent answer. I went down the Notification Center route because you're right with the first method and someone tapping a text field and not typing anything in, and also it was a chance to implement my first NSNotificationCenter code and a good chance to learn it. It works like an absolutely charm and I cannot thank you enough. I really appreciate your excellent assistance with this. I'd vote you up twice if I could! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by one of the methods

1. In ViewDidLoad() method disable the UIBarbutton
2. Delegate method of UITextField check for the condition.
   You can achieve this by having an variable declared and subsequently incrementing the count in 
   UITextFielddelegate 'textFieldShouldReturn' method.
3. Once condition is satisfied enable the save UIBarButton.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's very helpful. A quick question - how would I set the UIBarButton item to be disabled in viewDidLoad? It's created in Storyboard and there's an IBAction attached to the button rather than an IBOutlet.

Comment: Also, which delegate method of UITextField should I do the check?